# Is there any SQL Statement procedure or code for optional requested field value?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm a beginner. I created a database in vb.net and I need to build a query, in the SQL Statement - Table Adapter, which returns records even if parameters are NULL in one or more textbox. To be clear, I have several textboxes (related to fields) with which I can filter record results and I want to refine my research as much as I fill textboxes, reverse if I fill just one of them randomly.

Sorry if I confused you, but I guess you get it anyway.

Comment: There are a number of existing questions / answers for 'optional sql parameters', but linking to a specific one would require we knew which database this was for as the answers differ.

Answer (score 0):

In its simplest form (assuming SQL server param concepts)

```
-- Define your columns to pull back/display
select t1.column1, t1.column2, t1.column3...
-- Define the table, give it an alias if you're using more than one or it has a silly name
from thetable t1
-- Apply filters
where 
-- For each textbox/column search combo, do this...
(column1 = @field1 or @field1 is null)
or -- If the filter is restrictive, use AND here
(column2 = @field2 or @field2 is null)
or -- If the filter is restrictive, use AND here
...
```

Comment: Hi JohnHC, thank you for the answer. Should I write it in the SQL Statement as a normal SQL Code? I already tried the 'OR' at the begin but ti gives me more records than it should instead of refining the research.

Comment: If the filter applies for each value, swap the or for and

Comment: Doesn't work... If I fill just one of the fields it doesn't do anything, doesn't return any record.

Comment: @pb-beginner Is the param passing a null or an empty string? If the latter, exchange `null` for `''`

Comment: empty string... Should I write it in SQL Statement?

Answer (score 0):

I would dump the table adapter for this requirement.

I am building the sql string using a StringBuilder. StringBuilder objects are mutable, String is not.

To run this Code
1. I assumed Sql Server. If this is not the case change all the data object (Connectio and Command) to the proper provider.

2. Add your connection string to the constructor of the connection.
3. Add your table name where it says "YourTable"
4. I just used TextBox1 etc. as control names. Use your actual control names
5. Replace Field1, Field2 etc. with your actual column names.
6. The parameter names (by convention, they start with @) can be anything you want as long as they match the name you add to the Parameters collection.
7. You will have to check your database for the actual datatypes of the fields. Be sure to convert the TextBox values to the compatible type. TextBox.Text is a string so it will be compatible to .VarChar but note number types or dates.
8. I added a Debug.Print to check what the Sql string looks like. Be cautious about where I have spaces when building the string. You can see the result in the immediate window (available from Debug menu).
9. If you don't already have a DataGridView on your form, add one so you can see the reults of your query.

Finally, always use parameters, use Using...End Using blocks, and open your connection at the last minute.

```
Private Sub RunDynamicQuery()
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    Dim AndNeeded As Boolean
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand
            sb.Append("Select * From YourTable Where ")
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) OrElse Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox1.Text) Then
                sb.Append("Field1 = @Field1")
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Field1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
                AndNeeded = True
            End If
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox2.Text) OrElse Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox2.Text) Then
                If AndNeeded Then
                    sb.Append(" And")
                End If
                sb.Append(" Field2 = @Field2")
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Field2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text
                AndNeeded = True
            End If
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox3.Text) OrElse Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox3.Text) Then
                If AndNeeded Then
                    sb.Append(" And")
                End If
                sb.Append(" Field3 = @Field3")
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Field3", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox3.Text
                AndNeeded = True
            End If
            sb.Append(";")
            cmd.Connection = cn
            Debug.Print(sb.ToString)
            cmd.CommandText = sb.ToString
            cn.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```